# How to get urls of entries in wikipedia list articles?

Tags: wikidata, wikipedia

I am trying to retrieve the URL of all articles listed inside wikipedia list articles. For concreteness lets consider the wikimedia list article `List_of_American_scientists`

I know how to use the `wiki api` and the following query gives a decent result:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=jsonfm&titles=List_of_American_scientists

**But** the result that it returns is a list in a single string. I will have to parse this string and convert the names to wikipedia urls myself. Is there a better way to retrieve the answers that can directly gives me the urls of the pages?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but [parsing wikitext](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Parsing_wikitext) seems to return separate lists of internal and external links found in a wikitext document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [links](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Links) API property to get the titles of all the links on the page: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=jsonfm&titles=List_of_American_scientists&prop=links&pllimit=500. Note that this gives only the first 500, so you will need to make multiple queries to get them all, using `plcontinue`.

Comment: [With full URLs using generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=info&generator=links&inprop=url&titles=List_of_American_scientists&gpllimit=500) @Pushpendre

Answer (score 3):

You might also use the [SPARQL REST API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_query_service/User_Manual#SPARQL_endpoint) to query wiki data. E.g. [get](https://goo.gl/tvP5Ub) a table of US citizens whose occupation is a subclass of scientist:

```
PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>

SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?article WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q5.
  ?item wdt:P27 wd:Q30.
  ?item wdt:P106 ?occupation.
  ?occupation wdt:P279 wd:Q901.
  ?article schema:about ?item.
  ?article schema:inLanguage "en".
  ?article schema:isPartOf <https://en.wikipedia.org/>.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
GROUP BY ?item ?itemLabel ?article
ORDER BY ?itemLabel
LIMIT 1000
```