# Get section and page title from a list of articles in Wikipedia via API

Tags: wikidata, wikipedia

I want to get the different sections with their pages from the [Wikipedia:Featured articles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Featured_articles).

By following this [answer](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/9527/13467), I know I can get page titles of links as follows:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&titles=Wikipedia:Featured articles&prop=revisions&rvprop=content
```

The result looks something like this:

```
{
  "continue": {
    "plcontinue": "5921878|0|Barack_Obama",
    "continue": "||"
  },
  "query": {
    "pages": {
      "5921878": {
        "pageid": 5921878,
        "ns": 4,
        "title": "Wikipedia:Featured articles",
        "links": [
          {
            "ns": 0,
            "title": "...And Justice for All (album)"
          },
...
```

However, like that I don't get the section name under which each page/link is. For instance, "...And Justice for All (album)" lies under the Music section/header.

Is there a way to get 
i) the section each page belongs to or 
ii) the pages belonging to a section 
in the same or in a different query?

Comment: a) there has to be a way, perhaps not the solution you have so far, but that is how/why wikipedia's APIs are structured, to return their data.  
b) the music section that "And Justice for All" is under is denoted by the "<code> ==Music== * </code>" key word. I'm not familiar with Wikipedia's API, but there's got to be some way of tracing up the objects from "And Justice" to the key value, thats just how JSON works.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out I can get the section and then the pages/links for that section, in two separate queries like so:

1) Get the sections

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page=Wikipedia:Featured articles&prop=sections
```

With answer:

```
{
  "parse": {
    "title": "Wikipedia:Featured articles",
    "pageid": 5921878,
    "sections": [
...
      {
        "toclevel": 1,
        "level": "2",
        "line": "Music",
        "number": "21",
        "index": "33",
        "fromtitle": "Wikipedia:Featured_articles",
        "byteoffset": 121596,
        "anchor": "Music"
      },
...
}
```

2) Get the pages/links for a given section

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&format=json&page=Wikipedia:Featured articles&section=33&prop=links
```

To get:

```
{
  "parse": {
    "title": "Wikipedia:Featured articles",
    "pageid": 5921878,
    "links": [
      {
        "ns": 0,
        "exists": "",
        "*": "...And Justice for All (album)"
      },
...
}
```

I wish I could pipe this into a single query but I can't figure out how to use generators to do just that, maybe it's not supported.

In that case, parsing the wikitext/HTML text [as suggested by svick](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/9539/13467) may be the easiest way to go.

Answer (score 1):

No, MediaWiki does not track where in the page does a link come from, so you can't get this information directly from the API.

What you would need to do is to retrieve the article text (either as wikitext or HTML), and parse that yourself.